# Returning a non negative integer in descending order

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a Ruby challenge to take any non-negative integer as an argument and return it with its digits in descending order. Essentially, rearrange the digits to create the highest possible number.

for example:

```
Input: 145263 Output: 654321

Input: 123456789 Output: 987654321
```

Currently this is what my solution looks like:

```
def descending_order(n)
  # take any non-negative integer as an argument
  # return it with digits in descending order
   n.sqrt(1){ |digits| digits.sort_by.reverse }
  
end
```

However, it keeps throwing an error message saying:

```
 `descending_order': undefined method `sqrt' for 0:Integer (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: I don't see why you want to take the square root here, but in any case, Ruby does not have a method of this name. To get the square root of a number, do a `n**0.5`.

Comment: Why did you write `sqrt(1)`? What is that supposed to achieve?

Comment: @user1934428: ruby does have it as `Math.sqrt`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : Yes, I see. I should have said, that there is no instance method for this in the numeric classes. Of course the main problem is that taking the root here does not make sense. Plus, the OP edited the code that it now reads `n.sqrt(1)`, which is even more insane, as it seems to supply two arguments (n and 1). I now wonder whether the OP really wanted to calculate the root here, or maybe meant something completely different, and _sqrt_ was just a typo.

Comment: @user1934428: yeah, the sqrt does not make any sense here.

Answer (score 4):

```
def descending_order(n)
   n.to_s.split(//).sort.reverse.join.to_i  
end
```

This creates an array of strings, each string being a single digit as text. We can use the normal sort here, because we can reasonably assume that the collating sequence of the digits in an encoding obeys the same order than their numeric counterpart. In particular, we know that i.e. `'4' < '8'`.

Comment: so the sort method doesn't work directly on an integer ? we must have an array of strings in order for the .sort method to work? thank you for the explanation !

Comment: @KobadaTech : `sort`, by its nature, is defined on an ordered collection, i.e. on an `Array`. Think mathematically: What would it mean to sort a single item?

Comment: Instead of `.to_s.split(//)`, you can do `.digits`. And instead of `sort.reverse`, you could (although it makes insignificant difference here) do `.sort_by { |i| -i}` or equivalently `.sort_by(&:-@)`.

Comment: In other words, you can write this shorter, as: `n.digits.sort_by(&:-@).join.to_i`

Comment: @TomLord : Didn't know the `digits` method. Also, your approach to avoid `reverse` clever, and I have never seen the `@` opeator. Where is it definied? In any case you should post this as answer, as your solution is much leaner than mine.

Comment: @user1934428 `:-@` refers to the _unary minus_, e.g. `5.send(:-@) #=> -5` (negation) whereas  `:-` refers to the _binary minus_, e.g. `5.send(:-, 2) #=> 3` (subtraction). You would also use `def -@` do define the former. (same for unary plus, i.e. `+@`)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest to understand answer is:

```
n = 145263
n.digits.sort.reverse.join.to_i

n.digits                        => [3, 6, 2, 5, 4, 1]
n.digits.sort                   => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
n.digits.sort.reverse           => [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
n.digits.sort.reverse.join      => "654321"
n.digits.sort.reverse.join.to_i => 654321
```

#### Summary of methods

```
digits  => Returns the digits of ints place-value representation with radix base (default: 10). The digits are returned as an array with the least significant digit as the first array element.
sort    => Returns a new array created by sorting self.
reverse => Returns a new array containing selfs elements in reverse order.
join    => Returns a string created by converting each element of the array to a string, separated by the given separator. If the separator is nil, it uses current $,. If both the separator and $, are nil, it uses an empty string.
to_i    => Returns the result of interpreting leading characters in str as an integer base base (between 2 and 36).
```

I like Tom Lord's answer in his comment. It's a bit cryptic at first, but Stefan's explanation is excellent.